# ASP.NET 5 - Starting an ASP.NET vNext project

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

I am trying to get my feet wet with ASP.NET vNext. I'm very interested in the cross-platform aspect of it. For that reason, I'm focused on using the K Runtime Environment.

I've looked at the sample provided on the [home page](https://github.com/aspnet/home). Those samples do not help me though. I have a project that is structure like this:

```
/
 /client
 /server
  /controllers
   HomeController.cs
  /views
   /home
     Index.cshtml
  project.json
  Startup.cs
```

When I navigate to the directory with project.json, I run the following from the command-line.

```
C:\MyProject\server>k web
```

I get the following error:

```
System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'server' or one of its dependencies. General Exception (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131500)
File name: 'server' ---> Microsoft.Framework.Runtime.Roslyn.RoslynCompilationException: C:\MyProject\server\controllers\HomeController.cs(5,18): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Mvc' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Web' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
```

I feel like `Startup.cs` is looking for something called `server`. Yet it doesn't exist. I suspect something is missing from `project.json`. However, I do not know what. My `project.json` looks like the following:

```
{
    "dependencies": {
        "Kestrel": "1.0.0-beta1",
        "Microsoft.AspNet.Diagnostics": "1.0.0-beta1",
        "Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting": "1.0.0-beta1",
        "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc": "6.0.0-beta1",
        "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.WebListener": "1.0.0-beta1"
    },
    "commands": {
        "web": "Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting --server Microsoft.AspNet.Server.WebListener --server.urls http://localhost:5001"
    },
     "frameworks": {
        "aspnet50": {},
        "aspnetcore50": {}
  }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?  Thank you!

Comment: Look at your full error message - you have what appears to be a compilation error in `HomeController.cs` on line 5, position 18: `The type or namespace name 'Mvc' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Web' (are you missing an assembly reference?)` This could be causing the `server` issue.

Comment: The problem was in my controller. I was referencing System.Web.Mvc;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Tim has pointed out there's something fishy in your controllers.

The compiler asks for `System.Web` but you shouldn't use it. Is it referenced somewhere? `vNext` is moving away from System.Web; we should not use it in `MVC 6`.

Are you using the stock New Project? Are you using the latest CTP/Preview version?

If you are using the stock New Project just try recreate the project. Yes, I have solved an error in VS 2015 by only recreating the stock project.

I would recommend you to read this article:
http://www.dzone.com/articles/developing-and-self-hosting

Comment: When I make that change, I get a different error: `System.FormatException: The short switch '-server' is not defined in the switch
mappings.
   at Microsoft.Framework.ConfigurationModel.CommandLineConfigurationSource.Load
()
   at Microsoft.Framework.ConfigurationModel.Configuration.Add(IConfigurationSou
rce configurationSource)
   at Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting.Program.Main(String[] args)`

Comment: My bad, it looks like you actually need double dashes. I have updated my answer with some suggestion which I hope that will solve your problem. Keep us updated please.